# Time complexity of remove method with a given element value in dynamic array

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, dynamic-arrays, array-algorithms

As I am learning the data structures, I'm trying to implement the dynamic array in Java using the static array and trying to calculate the time complexities for each method.

For the remove method which takes an element as the parameter, my code contains an if statement to check if the given element is found in the array. Only if the element exists, it performs the remove operation.
I'm struggling to find the time complexity for this method. Is it O(n)? Can someone explain?

```
    public boolean remove(int ele) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == ele) {
                removeAt(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void removeAt(int index) {
        if (index > numberOfElements) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            for (int i = index; i < numberOfElements - 1; i++) {
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            }
            numberOfElements--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity seems to be O(N), with N to iterate over the array and N to do the shift operation once. One time the element is remove, the 'if' iterate over the rest of elements to do the shift, doing 'i' iterations to find the elements and 'n - i' iterations to shift it. In the end of the 'if', the outer 'for' is broken because the return and the operation finish.

I think you need to iterate until 'numberOfElements' and not work with 'array.length' directly.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks for the correction! I should iterate until numberOfElements but not arr.length. Coming to the time complexity, what I understood from your response is that it’s O(n) as the inner loop executes only once. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Inner the 'if' has a return that break the iteration. Then this runs 1 time.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting an element from an array takes O(n) time even if we are given index of the element to be deleted. The time complexity remains O(n) for sorted arrays as well.
In linked list, if we know the pointer to the previous node of the node to be deleted, we can do deletion in O(1) time.